# Programmatically entering data into a table field for an entry

Tags: plugin-development, entries

I now know that you can enter data into an entry's field by using `$event->params['entry']->getContent()->handle`

But let's say I have a foreach loop and I want to enter each line into an entry that is a table field. So for example:

```
foreach ($apigrab['properties'] as $specs) {
    $event->params['entry']->getContent()->specs == ??
}
```

Obviously each table heading has it's own handle and I don't imagine specs.handle would work in this case, and also how would you prevent it from just overwriting the same line over and over again? Would I have to count how many first and tell it specifically where to go?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that your "specs" field is a **table** field type?

Comment: @LindseyD Yep that's what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saving data to a Table field, here's the catch... Your field data is being condensed into **JSON** and stored in a **single database table cell**.

So ultimately, you'll want to have your Table field data arranged in an array, then use `json_encode` to prep it for entry into the database.

Here's an example of data for a Table field... This is a hypothetical field containing products, with a *Product Name* and prices for *Small*, *Medium*, and *Large*...

```
[
  {
    "col1": "Product #1",
    "col2": "5",
    "col3": "10",
    "col4": "15"
  },
  {
    "col1": "Product #2",
    "col2": "7",
    "col3": "14",
    "col4": "21"
  },
  {
    "col1": "Product #3",
    "col2": "7",
    "col3": "14",
    "col4": "21"
  }
]
```

**An important note...** The column names you established when setting up your Table field are not relevant here. Instead, each columnn will be referred to as "col1", "col2", "col3", etc.

Comment: Is this still a viable solution? I'm using similare json structure but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, this should still work. If you are having a similar issue, I recommend you [ask a new question...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Just a note in case anyone finds this - you do not want to use `json_encode` - use the actual array to set the value.