# Saving to table field via plugin

Tags: import, table-field, csv

I'm dealing with the import plugin, processing a .csv file. 
in the .csv there's a column with `|` separated values that shoud be inserted in a table field.
The entry are created correctly, also the table field ( just 1 column ) has the correct number of rows, but the content is empty ( `$featureContent` length is > 0 ).
Here's the code, what am I missing?

```
foreach ($fields as $handle => $value) {

   $value = explode('|', $value);
   $content[$handle] = array();

   foreach ( $value as $featureContent ) {                       
      $featuresRow = array( 'singleFeature' => $featureContent );
      array_push( $content[$handle], $featuresRow);                             
   }

 }
```

--- Edit ---

According to [this response](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1333/6817) the table data is stored in Json format, so now I'm trying to create the table providing a json formatted string.
As this:

```
[
  {"col1":"very beautiful"},
  {"col1":"really beautiful"},
  {"col1":"astonishing beautiful"}
```

]

Still, this doesn't work for me. It doesn't even creates the 3 rows as the other approach.

Answer (score 3):

The answer on [the previous question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1333/6817) is a little bit off - you **do not** want to use `json_encode` to save the field. Just use the actual array:

```
$tableValue = [
  [
    "col1": "Product #1",
    "col2": "5",
    "col3": "10",
    "col4": "15"
  ],
  [
    "col1": "Product #2",
    "col2": "7",
    "col3": "14",
    "col4": "21"
  ],
  [
    "col1": "Product #3",
    "col2": "7",
    "col3": "14",
    "col4": "21"
  ]
];

$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
  'tableField'=> $tableValue,
));
```

Note that 'col1', 'col2', etc, refer to locations in the table. The handle of the table column is not used.